# How do I show traffic information on map in my WP8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows phone 8 app to show current traffic information on the map but I don't see any help to achieve this. There is no help provided on MS Dev Centre as well.
I can't use Bing maps or Bing Map Task API as it is now deprecated. SO I am using MapsTask Class from Microsoft. Phone. Tasks assembly. But can't show traffic information programatically. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Traffic API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441725.aspx)

Here You have sample: [LINK](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/easily-include-bing-map-data-in-your.html) (but is for Windows 8)